# Scaling a UIComponent is not scaling its children

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, scale, children

I'm building a Flex application that creates neat vector images based on some options/filters. Relatively new to Flash/Flex/AS3, so I'm learning as I go..

In short:

```
// I create a new UIComponent
var myuic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();

// I then draw some vector graphics to it.. 
myuic_prev.graphics.beginFill(fgRGB, 1);
myuic_prev.graphics.drawRect(xptr, yptr, pxls, pxls);
myuic_prev.graphics.beginFill(fgRGB, 1);
myuic_prev.graphics.drawCircle(cx,cy,cr);
myuic.graphics.beginFill(fgRGB, 1);
myuic.graphics.drawCircle(cx,cy,cr);
myuic_prev.graphics.endFill();
```

For various reasons, the resulting image that gets produced may or may not fit in my Canvas or Display container, in this case a VBOX that has a fixed width.  In this case I 
have need to scale the resulting UIComponent image.

I read in the Adobe documentation that adjusting the scale of a UIComponent will appropriately scale its children.  In fact I see lots of threads about how to prevent this.

So I tried that... simply:

```
// Scale my UIC by changing the width
myuic_prev.width = 520;     
// Now make the two scale factors the same, this keeps proportions.
myuic_prev.scaleY = mxuic_prev.scaleX;
```

What I find is that this seems to scale the UIComponent itself, but NOT the children, or the shapes I drew into it.  The shapes now are out-of-bounds, or clipped running off the page.

What am I not understanding?  Are these shapes not being treated as children?  Or how do I make this work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `width` property for `UIComponent` works in a different way of its parent class `Sprite` because Flex components have a different resizing logic. In example modifing `width` or `height` do not affects the `graphics` layer. If you want to scale your `UIComponent` and the `graphics` layer try to use directly the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties.

Try this in example (if you want to scale by width to 520 and keep the aspect ratio):

```
component.scaleX = component.scaleY = 520 / component.width;
```

Comment: regarding your suggested edit to the question: The markdown in Stack Overflow will automatically format code (with syntax highlighting!) by indenting each line by 4 or more spaces. You shouldn't use the `<pre>` or `<code>` tags. Selecting an entire block and clicking the `{ }` icon in the toolbar will automatically add the leading spaces for you.

Comment: @CodyGray - Yep I saw your next edit and got the point. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. One of the goals of this "proposed edits" feature is to be a training ground for new users. The markdown support is something that a lot of people miss, since most forums don't have any support for it. Not everyone is as fast a learner as you. :-)